# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on the same partition?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, dell, boot-partition

I have a dell inspiron 1525, and it has already installed Windows 7. The problem is that the disk can't be partitioned, and I wanted to install ubuntu without uninstalling Windows 7.

Is it possible to have both installed on the same partition?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to install Ubuntu & windows  in same drive partition than you have use **wubi**.

That will help you install Ubuntu in same partition with windows.

here is link for how you can install Ubuntu using wubi.
[Help for Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

This will 100% work for you. I done so many times.